# How to work out the acceleration of an object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

I got given this question and im just lost.

> An object that weighs 25 kg experiences two perpendicular
>   forces of 80N and 50N respectively.
>
> What's the acceleration that object gets?

What i don't understand is how i would use that information to work out the answer.

Any Thought, I would like to know how you worked it out and what the answer is..

*I believe that it would be 30N as gravity is not in play here, nor would be mass of the object affect the acceleration due to unknown factors.*

Comment: What do you know about the acceleration of an object. How are Newton's Laws of motion applied here?

Comment: The problem statement should use the term _Force_ and not _Power_. Is this a translation issue?

Comment: BTW I googled `acceleration of an object from a force` and the first hit gave me your answer.

Comment: Yeah, i believed it to be that. But this was a question given to me by my college. So I cant really change the question. Thats most likely why i got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that these 2 perpendicular forces are the only forces acting on the body, there resultant can be easily found by parallelogram law of vectors. 
Using it i got the acting force as 94.34N and dividing by mass i got the acceleration as 3.77m/s2.

Note : Fnet^2 = F1^2 + F2^2 (from parallelogram law when angle between vectors is 90degrees)

Comment: Do you not also need to give the direction of the resultant you calculated?

Comment: Since we do not know the direction of either of the two forces , I believe that the person using the equations can find it wrt to the given direction of forces. Direction would not make much sense as neither of the forces have been mentioned with direction.

Comment: How about "A force of $94.34\text{ N}$  and an acceleration of $3.77 \frac{m}{s^2}$ , both in a direction between the two given forces, $32.00^\circ$ from the $80\text{ N}$ force"?

Answer (score 1):

One way we can set up - and solve - this problem is to think of things visually as vectors.

1. Draw a dot and label it "m = 25 kg"
2. Draw a short arrow in any direction (how about directly north?). Label it "$F_1 = 50$ N."
3. Start from the dot again and draw a longer arrow perpendicular to the first arrow. This can be either west or east because the question didn't specify directions. Label it "$F_2 = 80$ N." We drew it longer because 80 > 50.
4. Vector addition says that when adding vectors visually, we draw one vector $A$ point to tip, then add another vector $B$ by drawing another dot at the most recent tip and draw out the 2nd vector. How long the arrow is = the magnitude of the vector ("how much"); direction of arrow = direction (could be described in unit vectors or angle from one of the axes to the vector). So, once you place the vectors connected like I said, what shape does it look like?
5. Use a famous theorem to the resulting vector $C$ (which we draw from the point of $A$ to the tip of $B$).
6. Now that we have the magnitude of $C$ we can plug this into Newton's 2nd Law: $F = ma$. Solve for $a$.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration experienced by a body **along the line of force** can be calculated from Newton's 2nd law, that is:

$F = ma$

Rearranging,

$a = F / m$

So, you need to divide the sum of forces experienced by the body in a particular direction divided by its mass to calculate the acceleration.